# Hibernate many to many with extra column that repeats

Tags: spring, database, spring-boot, hibernate

So I want to set a table with additional attributes on a many to many situation.

```
public class Customer {
    private int id;
    // other attributes 
    // constructors
    // getters / setters
}
```

```
public class Product {
    private int id;
    // other attributes 
    // constructors
    // getters / setters
}
```

And then I have the "visit" class linking those previous 2

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Visit {

    @EmbeddedId
    private VisitId visitId = new VisitId();

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("customerId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_customer", nullable = false)
    private Customer customer;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("productId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_product", nullable = false)
    private Product product;

    private LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now();

    @Embeddable
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class VisitId implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private int customerId;
        private int productId;
    }
}
```

Tested
Customer 1 with Product 1
Customer 2 with Product 1

And it added to database. But If I tried to add once again Customer 1 with Product 1 when the date is not the same, ofc it does not work, because of the primary key being CustomerId and ProductId. How can I add another " private int id " to the primary key or just convert the date as a primary key as well?

Answer (score 0):

Since complex id (Customer & Product) is not unique you can just have a simple Id and the relationship to the tables as you specified.

```
@Id
private int visitId

@ManyToOne 
@JoinColumn(name = "id_customer", nullable = false)
private Customer customer;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_product", nullable = false)
private Product product;
```

and maybe add a [unique constrain](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/UniqueConstraint.html)

```
@Table(
uniqueConstraints=
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"id_customer", "id_product", date })
)
@Entity
public class Visit{
```

Comment: Thx for the answer, I'll try this.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to make date as primary key to respect domain concepts. So, move date field from Visit class to VisitId class:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Visit {

    @EmbeddedId
    private VisitId visitId = new VisitId();

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("customerId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_customer", nullable = false)
    private Customer customer;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("productId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_product", nullable = false)
    private Product product;

    @Embeddable
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class VisitId implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private int customerId;
        private int productId;
        private LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now();

    }
}
```